# add banner into video with Vast

Tags: vast

i start to work with vast to add ads into my video (pre-roll mid-roll and post-roll), i try to add banner into my video using XMl but i couldn't , if any one have a clew. this is my file XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE VAST [
  <!ATTLIST Ad    id    ID     #IMPLIED>
    <!ELEMENT MediaFiles (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT MediaFile (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT URL (#PCDATA)>
]>

<VAST version="2.0" >
<Ad id="mid-roll-0">
<InLine>
<AdSystem>2.0</AdSystem>
<AdTitle>Sample</AdTitle>
<Impression></Impression>
<Creatives>
<Creative sequence="1" id="2" >
<Linear>
<Duration>00:02:00</Duration>
<AdParameters>
</AdParameters>
<MediaFiles>
<MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="400" type="video/mp4">
<URL>vod/sample2.m4v</URL>
</MediaFile>
</MediaFiles>
</Linear>
</Creative>
</Creatives>
</InLine>
</Ad>
</VAST>
```

if some one help me to add a banner 250X60 in the first minute , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand, but if you try to show a banner inside the viewport of the video and have the video playing in the background, you should take a look at the NonLinear Ad Format ('overlay') in the VAST standard.

Comment: thanks, should i use add something in xml file or juste work with the js ? if you have an exemple, it will be great :D

Comment: Here's an old [sample](http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast2Nonlinear.xml) (taken from http://www.iab.com/insights/vast-2-0-xml-samples-for-testing/) that shows the basics. The VAST standard document itself is of course always wirth a read :-)